# What's the difference between abstract classes with zero parameters, and those with no parameters?

Tags: scala, inheritance, parameters, call, abstract-class

In Scala, what's the difference between:

```
abstract class Foo
// And
abstract class Bar()
```

There doesn't seem to be a difference between them when inheriting:

```
// All of these seem to work
case class FooA() extends Foo()
case class FooB() extends Foo

case class BarA() extends Bar()
case class BarB() extends Bar
```

Are these really all equivalent, or is there a difference? And if they *are* all equivalent, which abstract class definition should I use, `Foo` or `Bar`?

I know methods make this distinction because of currying. Can you curry when constructing a class? Is that why this weird duplication exists?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge currying is the reason why. I've never curried myself while constructing a class but I'm guessing it's possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference. An `abstract class` is just a `class` with the `abstract` modifier, which imposes the rule that you cannot instantiate it unless the abstract members are implemented in some way (whether through mixins, etc). And there is no difference been a parameterless class and a class with an empty parameter list. If a class has no parameter list, the compiler assumes an empty one.

This is stated clearly in the [SLS Section 5.3](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-definitions):

> If no formal parameter sections are given, an empty parameter section () is assumed.

Since they are equivalent, it's really just a matter of taste which you should use. I prefer to omit the parentheses for brevity, but the compiler will add them back in anyway.

The only time this can make things confusing is when you have a class with only implicit parameters. For example, this:

```
abstract class Foo(implicit bar: Bar)
```

is actually

```
abstract class Foo()(implicit bar: Bar)
```

which causes confusion when one tries to supply the implicit manually, and the parentheses must be supplied. e.g.

```
new Foo()(new Bar)
```

Comment: Excellent, this answers my question completely, thanks.